# What's the effect of SyntaxForm option in StandardForm boxes of Superscript?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, undocumented, boxes, precedence

Consider the following sample:

```
Superscript[w, 1] // MakeBoxes
(* TemplateBox[{"w", "1"}, "Superscript", SyntaxForm -> SuperscriptBox] *)
```

There's a mysterious `SyntaxForm -> SuperscriptBox` option in the output. If I understand the (somewhat brief) document of `SyntaxForm` correctly, it's an option related to precedence of operator, then why is it set in this case?

I try removing the option and `MakeExpression`, a `Superscript[…, …]` is still obtained:

```
TemplateBox[{"w", "1"}, "Superscript"] // MakeExpression
(* HoldComplete[Superscript[w, 1]] *)
```

Is this option just redundant? If not, can you show me example(s) that the option makes a difference?